# Eclipse with Texlipse plugin - adding sytem time into generated PDF file after compilation

Tags: texlipse

My question is focused on the possibility of an Eclipse IDE and its plugin Texlipse. After generating the PDF file, I would like to add the prefix (or something similar), which would include system time. I hope my question is at least somewhat understandable. I think that a similar problem solved everyone, who must distribute pdf files between other colleagues. I know it's a stupid way versioning, but simple.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put `\currenttime` in your tex file, e.g. in header or footer, to get the compile time in the pdf.

Comment: It is possible, but I would like to get something like \currenttime into file name of the generated pdf. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: I'm afraid it is not possible in Texlipse, since you could not set the compile option in Texlipse. Btw, if you use linux and can write compile the tex file from a console, you can use the follwing:

`pdflatex --output-dir=output/ --jobname=``date +%d_%m_%y-%H_%M_%S`` testtex.tex`

But this way will produce so many files. (for each compile times, you get new file and the old files are not deleted)

Comment: Please use only a single backquote (`) I don't know how to put the backquote in a literal/code String.